# Using MonoTouch 5, my images are not displayed in Interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using MonoTouch 5 and I'm trying to use images from my MonoTouch project in Interface Builder.  The images are available in IB and I'm able to drag them on the view, everything looks good in IB.  When I run my monotouch project, I don't see any images.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that when you make the reference to the image in IB, it will save that reference as 'myImage.png' even if the image you have is stored in 'Images/myImage.png' so when it comes to find the image in the root of your application, it is not there.

It might be worth filing this as a bug to see what we can do to get this fixed. Does moving your images from a folder into the root solve this issue?

ChrisNTR

Comment: I had this same problem the other day, and it was because the images were in a subfolder.  I just had to add the subfolder name in the Xcode image location box and it fixed it.